# How to reset counter?

Tags: android, count, launch

I want to show Interstitial ads whenever the app reaches 10 launches. So i count them with

```
OnCreate{
 prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = prefs.edit();
    totalCount = prefs.getInt("counter", 0);
    totalCount++;
    editor.putInt("counter", totalCount);
    editor.commit(); }
```

and whenever totalCount = 10 i run the add:

```
       if(totalCount==10){

                fullScreenAd2.show();

            }
```

Now i want to reset totalCount, how can i do this? 
i know that calling totalCount++ adds 1 point and totalCount-- removes 1 point. But how can i reset it to 0?

Comment: What about totalCount = 0?

Comment: no, this doesnt work.

Comment: not sure exactly what your are asking but you use totalCount=0 to reset it..

Comment: no this doesn't reset it. :(

Comment: Of course it works!

Comment: If it doesn't work then you just placed it wrong.

Comment: @GeorgeLungu post your full code...or explain more what you want to do..

Comment: i just realised that the "0" value of totalCount should be saved in order to get it after app restarts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just reset it to 0 after it becomes 10. For example:

```
   if(totalCount==10){
            fullScreenAd2.show();
            totalCount=0;  // and i think that, this should do it...
                editor.putInt("counter", totalCount); // call editor to save
                editor.commit();                      //totalCount's value
        }`
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = prefs.edit();
totalCount = prefs.getInt("counter", 0);

if(totalCount == 10){
    fullScreenAd2.show();
    totalCount = 0;
} else {
    totalCount++;
}
editor.putInt("counter", totalCount);
editor.commit();
```